# transfer content from one list to another

Tags: java, list

I have a small problem, I can't transfer content from one list to another.

This is exactly the place:

> MergeSort ms = new MergeSort(carList.get().getMark());

How can this be done?
Is the code I gave correct? I am open to any suggestions and hints :)

Help me run this, please

My main (I have a problem here):

```
package onlytest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OnlyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
        carList.add(new Car("Audi", 35000));
        carList.add(new Car("BMW", 39000));
        carList.add(new Car("Seat", 31000));
        carList.add(new Car("Skoda", 19000));

        MergeSort ms = new MergeSort(carList); //getMark
        ms.sort();
        ms.show();
    }

}
```

Class cars:

```
public class Car {

        private final String mark;

        private final int price;

        Car(String mark, int price){
            this.mark = mark;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getMark(){
            return mark;
        }

        public int getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Mark: "+mark+", price: "+price;
        }
    }
```

Add update from @Jason

And finally MergeSort function:

````
package onlytest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MergeSort {

    private List strList;
    public  MergeSort(List<Car> input) {
        strList = input;
    }

    public void sort() {
        strList = mergeSort(strList);
    }

    List<Car> mergeSort(List<Car> whole) {
        List<Car> left = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Car> right = new ArrayList<>();
        int center;

        if (whole.size() == 1) {    
            return whole;
        } else {
            center = whole.size()/2;
            for (int i=0; i<center; i++) {
                    left.add(whole.get(i));
            }

            for (int i=center; i<whole.size(); i++) {
                    right.add(whole.get(i));
            }

            left  = mergeSort(left);
            right = mergeSort(right);

            merge(left, right, whole);
        }
        return whole;
    }

    private void merge(List<Car> left, List<Car> right, List<Car> whole) {
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        int wholeIndex = 0;
        while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
            if ( (String.valueOf(left.get(leftIndex)).compareTo(String.valueOf(right.get(rightIndex)))) < 0) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                leftIndex++;
            } else {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                rightIndex++;
            }
            wholeIndex++;
        }

        List<Car> rest;
        int restIndex;
        if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
            rest = right;
            restIndex = rightIndex;
        } else {
            rest = left;
            restIndex = leftIndex;
        }

        for (int i=restIndex; i<rest.size(); i++) {
            whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
            wholeIndex++;
        }
    }

    public void show() {

        System.out.println("Mark:         Price:");
        for (int i=0; i< strList.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(strList.get(i));
        }
    }

}```
````

Comment: What exactly are you trying to merge/sort by?

Comment: Now i try to mergesort only mark, finally i need choose between 2-3 Strings

Comment: What? How can you merge the names of the cars?

Comment: Instead of telling how you want it done, instead explain what it is you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to make a mergesort algorithm that will operate on arraylist. List items must be objects

Comment: Why are you implementing the merge sort algorithm? Do you have to?

Comment: it is my Scholl guidelines for project

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't make any sense whatsoever unfortunately. Car should not be composed of 2 Lists of Car. It's clear by the implementation of the methods that those List's should be of type String and of type Integer.

```java
    public class Car {

        private final String mark;

        private final int price;

        Car(String mark, int price){
            this.mark = mark;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public String getMark(){
            return mark;
        }

        public int getPrice(){
            return price;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Mark: "+mark+", price: "+price;
        }
    }
```